# onActivityResult not called from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation, android-fragmentactivity

I have an activity which contains `BottomNavigationView` and `NavHostFragment`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_profile);

    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.myNavHostFragment);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);
```

I have also added `onActivityResult` method in this parent activity.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Parent onActivity",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

In the fragment, I have an `ImageView` in which I am using Intent to pick an image from the user.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/jpeg");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), RC_PHOTO_PICKER);
```

And in the fragment's `onActivityResult` I am doing this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"OnActivityResult",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // Result returned from launching the Intent to select image for profile
    if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The issue is `onActivityResult` is neither called in the parent activity and nor in the fragment.

I have tried various solutions provided in [Answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156404/onactivityresult-doesnt-call-from-viewpager-fragment), [Answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment), [Answer3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33698378/onactivityresult-is-not-called-when-startactivityresult-is-called-from-child). **But none of them are working!!**

Comment: What is your value of `RC_PHOTO_PICKER`? Is the `this` in `this.startActivityForResult` your Fragment?

Comment: @ianhanniballake value of `RC_PHOTO_PICKER` is 2 which is defined as constant and `this` refers to the fragment

Comment: Can you include the entry in the AndroidManifest.xml for your activity?

Comment: There is nothing inside it: `<activity android:name=".FirstScreen" />`

Comment: Are you using any other activity in your manifest? Particular any that are using `android:launchMode` in their manifest entries?

Comment: No any other activity uses `android:launchMode` in manifest file

Comment: Did you debug, that both on activityresults are not called or just didn't see the Toast Message? If you just looked for the message try replacing getActivity with getContext

Comment: I have tried logging, debugging and toast message, nothing is getting called

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `Intent.createChooser()` with `Intent.GET_CONTENT` - that's true for both activities and Fragments.

Instead, just use your Intent directly with `startActivityForResult`.

Comment: I got this code from the udacity course: `Firebase in a Weekend`: [Link](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud0352/lessons/fab5bf81-cfe5-4071-9afe-b6eb324a6257/concepts/37891f6f-56f7-42b8-9c6f-8e597d16a03f). Let me try your suggestions.

Comment: Still not able to solve the issue. Not even called in parent activity also :(

Comment: Does the other activity start at all?

Comment: `onCreate` is only called in parent activity which contains the `navHostFragment`

Comment: No, I mean does the `GET_CONTENT` activity appear on the screen after you call `startActivityForResult`?

Comment: Yes it does. I am also able to view all the images in the gallery. But after selecting the image, nothing happens :(

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code block to parent onActivityResult

```
for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
   //send result to all child fragment
       if(fragment!=this)
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: I have used `Toast` in parent activity also and it is not being called

Answer (score 0):

not too sure but could it be that the intent is being invoked by the fragment? can you please try to use a listener on when the imageView or button is clicked and then intercept it and invoke the intent from the parent activity?